# Use jQuery to make a NEW instance of angularJS array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-accordion

I am working with Angular and jQuery

I have div "A", pulling content via angular

```
<div class="a">
   <p ng-repeat="banana in bananas">{{banana}}</p>
</div>
```

I have ul class "B"

```
<ul class="b">
  <li>content 1</li>
  <li>content 2</li>
  <li>content 3</li>
<ul>
```

When any of the `li` inside "B" is clicked insert that `li` in `.accordion`

```
//this works fine    
$(".b li").click(function () {
   $(this).clone().appendTo(".accordion");
 });
```

The problem is when I want to do the same thing for div "A"... div "A" is inserted on the LAST appended `li`

jQuery accordion div, its empty,

```
<div class="accordion">
</div>
```

and am trying to create a NEW instance of div "A" everytime a `li` is clicked then must be inserted as a NEW child of the accordion so that it can work independently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class "A" must be created within jQuery, then inserted

```
myVar = $("<div class="a"><p ng-repeat="banana in bananas">{{banana}}</p></div>");


$(".b li").click(function () {
   $(this).clone().append(myVar).appendTo(".accordion");
});
```